# VS 2008: Fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: ...: Invalid argument

Tags: visual-c++, invalid-argument

I've seen lots of questions about Fatal Error C1083 "No such file or directory", but in my case I am seeing "Invalid argument".

I am on 32-bit Windows trying to compile some C++ code which uses Boost. This used to work, so something in our setup must've changed, but the error is odd enough that I'm having trouble tracking it down.

I am using the CL compiler on the command line via CMake/jom. The exact error is:

```
c:\path\to\my\boost\installation\boost/math/constants/constants.hpp(12): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'boost/math/tools/precision.hpp': Invalid argument
```

constants.hpp looks fine, and unsurprisingly has the following as line 12:

```
#include <boost/math/tools/precision.hpp>
```

The invocation of `cl` contains `-IC:\path\to\boost\include`, and this is late in the compile of a big project which includes other boost headers. The problem seems to come and go, and the last time I saw it, it was at an include of afxwin.h, I think. But it's always "Invalid Argument".

Thanks in advance for any help, this one is driving us crazy.

Comment: This sounds like a WinAPI error to me, not something related to C++. Looks like Windows just cannot open the file for some weird reason. If it's a network drive, try to move it to local drive. Try disabling antivirus.

Comment: Thanks. Good suggestion, although no antivirus running on that machine. And the file is on a local drive...

Comment: Clearly you have a problem with the include path.  Yet you thought it was a good idea to post a junk path name.  That's odd...

Comment: I don't believe it's that clear. The boost include path is the same for all the source files in this large project, and the other ones don't fail to access the include files (albeit different boost files).

Comment: Looking at Jenkins, I can see this same setup built yesterday, but the day before I got this error:

`C:\winsame\volatile-vs9\txbase-r1297-ser\include\TxIoBase.h(23) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'cstddef': Invalid argument`